# rxjs add to/remove from an observable of array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

The following code has got compiling errors saying the return of `concat` cannot be assigned to an `Observable`. So how can I achieve the following?

```
let o1$: Observable<Object[]> = this.apiService.get();
let o2$: Observable<Object> = of({ a: "b" });
let o1$ = concat(o1$, o2$);
```

Plus how can I remove an `Object` from `o1$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables don't work that way. They aren't synchronous, so operations like remove or push to/from an observable don't work since you don't have the full data-set available to you. It's more/less a stream.

Instead, you filter, skip, take n, or any other filtering operation, the stream:

```
o1$.filter(o => isGood(o));
```

Or combine, forkJoin, combineLatest, etc., multiple streams:

```
merge(a$, b$)
```

[Operators by Category](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html)

I hope this helps!